# Python Module Error only in Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, python-import

I am working in Python 2.7.11 and Windows 10 and I have this package tree:

```
Application/
   __init__.py
   model/
       my_model.py
       __init__.py
   view/
       my_view.py
       __init__.py
   controller/
       my_controller.py
       __init__.py
```

I try to import **my_view.py** into **my_controller.py**:

My file my_controller.py:

```
import view.my_view
class Hello(object):
   def __init__(self):
       print "hello world"
```

But I have an *ImportError: No module named view.my_view*. I don't know why, this example work in Wnindows 7. Thank you.
Btw, I have readed documentation from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: does `import Application.view.my_view` work?

Comment: @danidee Now I have this error: *ImportError: No module named Application.view.my_view*

Comment: you know your folder name has to be named Application right?...if it isn't change the code to the appropriate folder name... or just rename the to Application (if you don't mind)

Comment: Wow, this is crazy, I have changed the app name and working again, Magic? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to import without specifying the top-level package name include this in your top-level `__init__.py` file

```
from Application import view
```

Then the view module will be loaded and you can easily import it in your code

Answer (score 0):

you shoule make sure that the dir application is in you sys.path, if not, use sys.path.insert to add it.

more information in https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages